# Logging to a single file from multiple processes in multiple modules

Tags: python, logging, module, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) I found [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes), I would like to use it with multiple modules, each module is a process, do you have any idea?
I used first code in the [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes).
Lets say the **main** in module, and **worker_process** in another, how to do that?
main.py:

```
def listener_configurer():
    root = logging.getLogger()
    h = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('mptest.log', 'a', 300, 10)
    f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    h.setFormatter(f)
    root.addHandler(h)

def listener_process(queue, configurer):
    configurer()
    while True:
        try:
            record = queue.get()
            if record is None:  # We send this as a sentinel to tell the listener to quit.
                break
            logger = logging.getLogger(record.name)
            logger.handle(record)  # No level or filter logic applied - just do it!
        except Exception:
            import sys, traceback
            print('Whoops! Problem:', file=sys.stderr)
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)


def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)
    listener = multiprocessing.Process(target=listener_process,
                                       args=(queue, listener_configurer))
    listener.start()
    workers = []
    for i in range(10):
        worker = worker_process.TEST(queue)

        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()
    for w in workers:
        w.join()
    queue.put_nowait(None)
    listener.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

worker_process.py

```
def worker_configurer(queue):
    h = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(queue)
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(h)

    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)



class TEST(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, queue, func=worker_configurer):
        super(TEST, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.func = func

        self.LEVELS = [logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO, logging.WARNING,
              logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL]

        self.LOGGERS = ['a.b.c', 'd.e.f']

        self.MESSAGES = [
        'Random message #1',
        'Random message #2',
        'Random message #3',
        ]

    def run(self):
        self.func(self.queue)
        name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        print('Worker started: %s' % name)
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(random())
            logger = logging.getLogger(choice(self.LOGGERS))
            level = choice(self.LEVELS)
            message = choice(self.MESSAGES)
            logger.log(level, message)
        print('Worker finished: %s' % name)
```

This is not work correctly, I would like to use the code (first code) in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) with multiple modules, as I mentioned before.

Comment: In your `main`, before calling any processes you should call the [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) and then simply doing [`logger = logging.getLogger()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) in each module should work fine.

Comment: @Shahad "doesn't work" is a totally useless description of a problem. For your next questions, please explain as clearly as possible __how__ it "doesn't work". You may want to read [ask] and [mcve]...